# Getting KeyError while Training my Dataset for ESRGAN Super Resolution Task

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, google-colaboratory, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to implement a type of GAN (Generative Adversarial Networks) named RS-ESRGAN to my satellite imagery dataset. You can check the github page of it if you like(https://github.com/luissalgueiro/rs-esrgan/tree/master). Here is the complete script I run on google colab:

```
!git clone https://github.com/luissalgueiro/rs-esrgan.git

!pip install lmdb
!pip install earthpy
!pip install tensorboardX

!cp /content/rs-esrgan/utils -r /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-package

import pandas
import matplotlib
import math
import torch
import json
import torch.nn as nn
import numpy as np
from skimage.metrics import peak_signal_noise_ratio

# Loading a JSON File to a Python Dictionary

with open('/content/rs-esrgan/options/train/train_ESRGAN_WV_5x_ALL.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

print(data)

# Data to be written
dictionary =  {'name': 'P41_ESRGAN_ALL_L1_x5_PREUP_FT_StanData', 'use_tb_logger': True, 'model': 'srragan', 'scale': 5, 'gpu_ids': [0], 'datasets': {'train': {'name': 'GDAL', 'mode': 'LRHR', 'data_IDs': '/content/dataset/bandas_all.csv', 'dataroot_HR': '/content/dataset/train_HR', 'dataroot_LR': '/content/dataset/train_LR', 'subset_file': None, 'use_shuffle': True, 'n_workers': 1, 'batch_size': 2, 'HR_size': 140, 'use_flip': True, 'use_rot': True, 'stand': True, 'LR_down': False, 'PreUP': True, 'norm': False, 'up_lr': False, 'HF': False, 'scale': 5}, 'val': {'name': 'val_GDAL', 'mode': 'LRHR', 'data_IDs': '/content/dataset/valid.csv', 'dataroot_HR': '/content/dataset/valid_HR', 'dataroot_LR': '/content/dataset/valid_LR', 'HR_size': 140, 'stand': True, 'norm': False, 'LR_down': False, 'PreUP': True, 'up_lr': False, 'HF': False, 'scale': 5}}, 'path': {'root': '/content/drive/MyDrive/BasicSR', 'work_root': '/content/drive/MyDrive/BasicSR_2020/', 'resume_state': None}, 'network_G': {'which_model_G': 'RRDB_net', 'norm_type': None, 'mode': 'CNA', 'nf': 64, 'nb': 23, 'in_nc': 3, 'out_nc': 3}, 'network_D': {'which_model_D': 'discriminator_vgg_128', 'norm_type': None, 'act_type': 'leakyrelu', 'mode': 'CNA', 'nf': 64, 'in_nc': 3}, 'train': {'lr_G': 0.0001, 'weight_decay_G': 0, 'beta1_G': 0.9, 'lr_D': 0.0001, 'weight_decay_D': 0, 'beta1_D': 0.9, 'lr_scheme': 'MultiStepLR', 'lr_steps': [20000, 40000, 60000, 80000], 'lr_gamma': 0.5, 'pixel_criterion': 'l1', 'pixel_weight': 0.01, 'feature_criterion': 'l1', 'feature_weight': 1, 'gan_type': 'vanilla', 'gan_weight': 0.005, 'manual_seed': 100, 'niter': 101000, 'val_freq': 10000}, 'logger': {'print_freq': 100, 'save_checkpoint_freq': 10000}}

json_object = json.dumps(dictionary, indent=4)

# Writing to sample.json
with open("sample.json", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(json_object)

!python /content/rs-esrgan/train_esrgan_WV.py -opt /content/sample.json
```

- First of all, I cloned the git repo.
- Then, I created a folder inside google colab content part for uploading my dataset.
- I copied all the important folders of the repository (data, models, options and utils folders) into usr/local/lib/Python3.10/dist-packages folder to import the custom packages of the repo.
- I converted train file (.json format) to python dict. Then, I copied the output and pasted into the next line's dictionary part and created sample.json file which is the file I use for training.
- Lastly, I started the training. It was working fine at first but after a couple of hours, I got this error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/rs-esrgan/train_esrgan_WV.py", line 299, in <module>
    main()
  File "/content/rs-esrgan/train_esrgan_WV.py", line 188, in main
    sr_img = util.tensor2imgStand(visuals['SR'], MeanVal = val_data["LR_mean"], StdVal = val_data["LR_std"])  # uint16
KeyError: 'LR_mean'
```

I thought this error might result from some missing lines in LRHR_dataset.py file which is in data folder in the repo so I tried to add some lines to define LR_mean, LR_std in the python file but I could not solve the problem. Here is the content of LRHR_dataset.py:

```
import os.path
import random
import numpy as np
import cv2
import torch
import torch.utils.data as data
import data.util as util


class LRHRDataset(data.Dataset):
    '''
    Read LR and HR image pairs.
    If only HR image is provided, generate LR image on-the-fly.
    The pair is ensured by 'sorted' function, so please check the name convention.
    '''

    def __init__(self, opt):
        super(LRHRDataset, self).__init__()
        self.opt = opt
        self.paths_LR = None
        self.paths_HR = None
        self.LR_env = None  # environment for lmdb
        self.HR_env = None

        # read image list from subset list txt
        if opt['subset_file'] is not None and opt['phase'] == 'train':
            with open(opt['subset_file']) as f:
                self.paths_HR = sorted([os.path.join(opt['dataroot_HR'], line.rstrip('\n')) \
                        for line in f])
            if opt['dataroot_LR'] is not None:
                raise NotImplementedError('Now subset only supports generating LR on-the-fly.')
        else:  # read image list from lmdb or image files
            self.HR_env, self.paths_HR = util.get_image_paths(opt['data_type'], opt['dataroot_HR'])
            self.LR_env, self.paths_LR = util.get_image_paths(opt['data_type'], opt['dataroot_LR'])

        assert self.paths_HR, 'Error: HR path is empty.'
        if self.paths_LR and self.paths_HR:
            assert len(self.paths_LR) == len(self.paths_HR), \
                'HR and LR datasets have different number of images - {}, {}.'.format(\
                len(self.paths_LR), len(self.paths_HR))

        self.random_scale_list = [1]

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        # print("EJecuta GeT ITEM")
        HR_path, LR_path = None, None
        scale = 0 #self.opt['scale']
        HR_size = self.opt['HR_size']

        # get HR image
        HR_path = self.paths_HR[index]
        img_HR = util.read_img(self.HR_env, HR_path)
        # modcrop in the validation / test phase
        if self.opt['phase'] != 'train':
            # print("Opcion: ", self.opt["phase"])
            img_HR = util.modcrop(img_HR, scale)
        # change color space if necessary
        if self.opt['color']:
            img_HR = util.channel_convert(img_HR.shape[2], self.opt['color'], [img_HR])[0]

        # get LR image
        if self.paths_LR:
            LR_path = self.paths_LR[index]
            img_LR = util.read_img(self.LR_env, LR_path)
        else:  # down-sampling on-the-fly
            # randomly scale during training
            if self.opt['phase'] == 'train':
                random_scale = random.choice(self.random_scale_list)
                H_s, W_s, _ = img_HR.shape

                def _mod(n, random_scale, scale, thres):
                    rlt = int(n * random_scale)
                    rlt = (rlt // scale) * scale
                    return thres if rlt < thres else rlt

                H_s = _mod(H_s, random_scale, scale, HR_size)
                W_s = _mod(W_s, random_scale, scale, HR_size)
                img_HR = cv2.resize(np.copy(img_HR), (W_s, H_s), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
                # force to 3 channels
                if img_HR.ndim == 2:
                    img_HR = cv2.cvtColor(img_HR, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

            H, W, _ = img_HR.shape
            # using matlab imresize
            img_LR = util.imresize_np(img_HR, 1 / scale, True)
            if img_LR.ndim == 2:
                img_LR = np.expand_dims(img_LR, axis=2)

        if self.opt['phase'] == 'train':
            # if the image size is too small
            # print("1...........")
            H, W, _ = img_HR.shape
            if H < HR_size or W < HR_size:
                img_HR = cv2.resize(
                    np.copy(img_HR), (HR_size, HR_size), interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
                # using matlab imresize
                img_LR = util.imresize_np(img_HR, 1 / scale, True)
                if img_LR.ndim == 2:
                    img_LR = np.expand_dims(img_LR, axis=2)

            H, W, C = img_LR.shape
            LR_size = HR_size #// scale

            # randomly crop
            rnd_h = random.randint(0, max(0, H - LR_size))
            rnd_w = random.randint(0, max(0, W - LR_size))
            img_LR = img_LR[rnd_h:rnd_h + LR_size, rnd_w:rnd_w + LR_size, :]
            rnd_h_HR, rnd_w_HR = int(rnd_h * scale), int(rnd_w * scale)
            img_HR = img_HR[rnd_h_HR:rnd_h_HR + HR_size, rnd_w_HR:rnd_w_HR + HR_size, :]

            # augmentation - flip, rotate
            img_LR, img_HR = util.augment([img_LR, img_HR], self.opt['use_flip'], \
                self.opt['use_rot'])

        # change color space if necessary
        if self.opt['color']:
            img_LR = util.channel_convert(C, self.opt['color'], [img_LR])[0] # TODO during val no definetion

        # BGR to RGB, HWC to CHW, numpy to tensor
        if img_HR.shape[2] == 3:
            img_HR = img_HR[:, :, [2, 1, 0]]
            img_LR = img_LR[:, :, [2, 1, 0]]


        img_HR = torch.from_numpy(np.ascontiguousarray(np.transpose(img_HR, (2, 0, 1)))).float()
        img_LR = torch.from_numpy(np.ascontiguousarray(np.transpose(img_LR, (2, 0, 1)))).float()
        # print("2.................................")
        #
        # print(img_HR.shape)

        if LR_path is None:
            LR_path = HR_path
        return {'LR': img_LR, 'HR': img_HR, 'LR_path': LR_path, 'HR_path': HR_path}

    def __len__(self):
        # print("EJecuta LEN")

        return len(self.paths_HR)
```

I ran out of my python knowledge here. Where and how in this LRHR_dataset.py file should I make changes to add new lines?